# What is Passed to the JavaScript replace() Function?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I've seen `str.replace(..., ...)` passed a function for its second argument.  What is passed to the function?  It goes like this:

```
"string_test".replace(/(.*)_(.*)/, function(a, b) { return a + b; } )
```

How do you get it to pass the matched groups to the function?  What are `a` and `b` in this case if anything?  I've been getting `undefined`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument is the entirety of a match, and the rest represent the matched groups. Basically it's like the array returned from `.match()`.

If the regex has the "g" modifier, then obviously the function is called over and over again.

Example:

```
var s = "hello out there";

s.replace(/(\w*) *out (\w*)/, function(complete, first, second) {
  alert(complete + " - " + first + " - " + second);
  // hello out there - hello - there
});
```

*edit* — in the function, if you want the matched groups as an array, you can do:

```
s.replace(/(\w*) *out (\w*)/, function(complete, first, second) {
  var matches = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
  alert(matches[0] + " - " + matches[1] + " - " + matches[2]);
  // hello out there - hello - there
});
```

Of course, as I wrote above that's what you get from the `.match()` method too.

Comment: How can I get an array of all the matched groups within the function?  I know I could use match and define the RegEx as a variable but it'd be great to know if something else is possible.

Answer (score -1):

I really do not want to copy the MDN Docs with their explanation: [Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)